# Memory of local variables gets reallocated - why

Tags: c++

Hello folks,

i'm trying to implement a function, that is supposed to read a binary file.
At a certain point in the code, i always get a memory access error.
I already know, that it is because the memory addresses of my local variables change, after i call a certain function, even though the function has nothing to do with my local variables.
May anyone be able to tell me what i'm doing wrong?
Here's my code:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdint>


//all Blocks from .sum in form of struct
struct HMDSPEC{
  int value1;
  int value2;
};

struct TIME{
  double value;
  std::string dimension;
};

struct DATE{
  int day;
  std::string month;
  int year;
};

//global variables

HMDSPEC hmdspec;
TIME scheduledTime;
DATE date;


void EraseSpaces(char* arr,std::string &s) {
  for(int i = 0; i < 8 ;i++){
    if(std::isspace(arr[i])){
      arr[i]='\0';
    }
  }
  s=std::string(arr);
}

void readHMDSPEC(std::ifstream &reader){
  std::cout<<"in HMDSPEC -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
  std::cout << &hmdspec<<std::endl;
  std::cout << &hmdspec.value1 << std::endl;
  std::cout << &hmdspec.value2 << std::endl;
  int sizeOfhmdspecBody;
  reader.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sizeOfhmdspecBody), 8);
  std::cout<<"in HMDSPEC nach 1st lesen-> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
  std::cout << &sizeOfhmdspecBody << std::endl;
  reader.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&hmdspec.value1), sizeOfhmdspecBody/2);
  std::cout<<"in HMDSPEC nach 2nd lesen-> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
  std::cout << &hmdspec<<std::endl;
  std::cout << &hmdspec.value1 << std::endl;
  reader.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&hmdspec.value2), sizeOfhmdspecBody/2);
  std::cout<<"in HMDSPEC nach 3rd lesen-> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
  std::cout << &hmdspec.value2 << std::endl;
}

void readTIME(char *word, std::ifstream &reader){
  reader.read(word,8);
  reader.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&scheduledTime.value),8);
  reader.read(word, 8);
  EraseSpaces(word,scheduledTime.dimension);
}



void RcppReadSumBin(std::string fname)
{
  std::ifstream reader(fname,std::ios::binary|std::ios::in);
  std::string s;
  s.reserve(512);
  char word[8];
  std::cout<<"Nach deklaration -> Adresse von word : " << &word << std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Nach deklaration -> Adresse von s : " << &s << std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Nach deklaration -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
  s.reserve(256);
  reader.read(word, 8);
  std::cout<<"Nach erstem einlesen -> Adresse von word : " << &word << std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Nach erstem einlesen -> Adresse von s : " << &s << std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Nach erstem einlesen -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
  EraseSpaces(word,s);
  std::cout<<"Nach eraseSpaces -> Adresse von word : " << &word << std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Nach eraseSpaces -> Adresse von s : " << &s << std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Nach eraseSpaces -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
  int i =0;
  std::cout<<"Vor while -> Adresse von word : " << &word << std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Vor while -> Adresse von s : " << &s << std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Vor while -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
  std::cout<<"Vor while -> Adresse von i : " << &i << std::endl;
  while(s!="ENDFILE"){
    reader.read(word,8);
    std::cout<<"Nach nächstem read -> Adresse von word : " << &word << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach nächstem read -> Adresse von s : " << &s << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach nächstem read -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach nächstem read -> Adresse von i : " << &i << std::endl;
    EraseSpaces(word,s);
    std::cout<<"Nach eraseSpaces -> Adresse von word : " << &word << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach eraseSpaces -> Adresse von s : " << &s << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach eraseSpaces -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach eraseSpaces -> Adresse von i : " << &i << std::endl;
    if(s=="HMDSPEC"){
      std::cout<<"In HMDSPEC -> Adresse von word : " << &word << std::endl;
      std::cout<<"In HMDSPEC -> Adresse von s : " << &s << std::endl;
      std::cout<<"In HMDSPEC -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
      std::cout<<"In HMDSPEC -> Adresse von i : " << &i << std::endl;
      readHMDSPEC(reader);
      std::cout<<"Nach readHMDSPEC -> Adresse von word : " << &word << std::endl;
      std::cout<<"Nach readHMDSPEC -> Adresse von s : " << &s << std::endl;
      std::cout<<"Nach readHMDSPEC -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
      std::cout<<"Nach readHMDSPEC -> Adresse von i : " << &i << std::endl;
    }else if (s=="TIME"){
      readTIME(word,reader);
      std::cout << scheduledTime.value << std::endl;
      std::cout << scheduledTime.dimension << std::endl;
    }/*else if (s=="DATE"){
      readDATE();
    }else if (s=="CELLDATA"){
      readCELLDATA();
    }else if (s=="CONNDATA"){
      readCONNDATA();
    }else if (s=="SRCDATA"){
      readSRCDATA();
    }else if (s=="FPCEDATA"){
      readFPCEDATA();
    }else if (s=="FPCODATA"){
      readFPCODATA();
    }*/
    std::cout<<"Nach if -> Adresse von word : " << &word << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach if -> Adresse von s : " << &s << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach if -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach if -> Adresse von i : " << &i << std::endl;
    i++;
    std::cout<<"Nach i++ -> Adresse von word : " << &word << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach i++ -> Adresse von s : " << &s << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach i++ -> Adresse von reader : " << &reader << std::endl;
    std::cout<<"Nach i++ -> Adresse von i : " << &i << std::endl;
  }
  reader.close();
}

int main ()
{
    std::string filename="SPE1.0000.SUM";

    RcppReadSumBin(filename);

    exit(0);
}
```

When i print the adresses it looks like this (for example)
before readHDMSPEC:
word : 0x7ffded9a42b0
s : 0x7ffded9a42c0
reader : 0x7ffded9a42e0
i : 0x7ffded9a42ac

after readHDMSPEC:
word :   0x7ffcfffffdb0
s :      0x7ffcfffffdc0
reader : 0x7ffcfffffde0
i :      0x7ffcfffffdac

Thank you

Comment: I'm sorry, but I don't see how you're determining that the addresses change, and I do not believe you if you're claiming that they do so within the scope of one execution of `RcppReadSumBin()`.

Comment: These variables are allocated on the stack and reclaimed immediatelly once you exit the method. Why do you care about the memory address though? You shouldn't be using pointers in the first place - you already use references for *some* of your arguments.

Comment: Please include [mcve]. In the example presented - I don't see where you are printing any addresses.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius These addresses can easily come from a debugger.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius local variables are allocated on the stack. Their address will be different from one call to the next.

Comment: @Angew _Can_ doesn't mean that they _come_ from the debugger. Especially, combined with OPs statement of _When i print the adresses it looks like this_. It implies.. Well.. Printing them.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Yes.. I know that? What, in my comment, implied that I didn't? All I said, that OPs example was not complete/verifiable, due to him expecting some output, that could not be achieved with example provided.

Comment: I purposely deleted all printouts of the addresses to make the code more readable. but i can put them back in if it helps.

Comment: @AlgirdasPreidžius the current code is enough to explain the issue. There's no need to post code that prints the addresses. Stack allocated ==> different addresses.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos And, what, in the question, led you to believe that the change in addresses, were between several calls to the same function?

Comment: I'd say, the title and looking at the variables in question. Besides, it wasn't just me. There are 3 good answers based on that code

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a very problematic thing:

```
int sizeOfhmdspecBody;
reader.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sizeOfhmdspecBody), 8);
```

I don't know of any platform where `sizeof(int) == 8`. Even on 64-bit systems the size of an `int` is four bytes. This will lead to the program writing out of bounds of the `sizeOfhmdspecBody` variable, which leads to *undefined behavior*, making the whole program *ill-formed*.

Solution? Don't use hard-coded [magic numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magic_number_(programming)). Instead use e.g. `sizeof sizeOfhmdspecBody` as the size.

And if the data in the file is 8 bytes (64 bits) then use `int64_t` as the type instead, or an array of `uint8_t` for the correct size.

And as noted by Lou Franco in a comment the next two lines will do bad things as well if the value of `sizeOfhmdspecBody` is not equal to `sizeof(int)`.

Comment: Also using that read size on the next lines to read in two more ints is bad.  The size had better be sizeof(int) *2 or the next two lines make no sense

Comment: Using `sizeof( sizeOfhmdspecBody)` could be not quite correct in this case, if 8 bytes are specified by protocol, not by data size.

Comment: The file i'm reading has a very specific format and the variable this particular part, that is read into the variable sizeOfhmdspecBody is specified as an "8 byte integer" in the documentation of the file format.

Comment: @Myrkjartan Then you can't use plain `int`. You must use a type which is *at least* 8 bytes big.

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude You are absolutely correct. I changed the type to int64_t and the memory access error is gone. I guess i will have to read up on data types and their memory....

Comment: @Myrkjartan I make it a habit of never hard coding the size of objects.  Even if you know the size of int64_t you should still use `sizeof(int64_t)`.  This usually gets optimized out by the compiler and will save you a headache down the road if you were using a union or class and it changes for some reason.

Answer (score 5):

This is the culprit:

```
int sizeOfhmdspecBody;
reader.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sizeOfhmdspecBody), 8);
```

You're reading 8 bytes into an `int`, but on most (if not all) common platforms, `sizeof(int)` is 4. If you know there will be 8 bytes in the data stream, use a suitable type like `std::int64_t` instead of `int`.

Answer (score 4):

You should be careful when using reinterpret cast. In this code:

```
int sizeOfhmdspecBody;
reader.read(reinterpret_cast<char *>(&sizeOfhmdspecBody), 8);
```

you assume, that `int` is 8 bytes, but looks like that is not the case and you override memory after that variable (breaking stack). You should use `int64_t` instead of `int` and put assert statement in your code, that `sizeof(sizeOfhmdspecBody) == 8`

Comment: Good idea suggesting an assertion; it could even be a `static_assert`.